# Python - os.fork() failure

Tags: python, fork

In python, I am using os.fork() within a for condition. I am doing something like this:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    try:
         pid = os.fork()
    except OSError:
         print ("Error forking process")
         continue
    if pid == 0:
         print "In child process"
         os._exit(0)
    print "In parent process"
```

How do I simulate a failure of os.fork() so that I can be sure that "In parent process" is not printed? How to simulate OSError for os.fork() function?

Comment: ... why do you need to do that? Are you trying to write a test? In that case you want to *mock* the `os.fork` function. Try checking `unittest.mock`. Otherwise I don't see any reason to do what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `os.fork()` with your own implementation:

```
import os

def _fork():
   raise OSError()
os.fork = _fork

for i in range(1,4):
    try:
         pid = os.fork()
    except OSError:
         print ("Error forking process")
         continue
    if pid == 0:
         print "In child process"
         os._exit(0)
    print "In parent process"
```

If this is part of a test, have a look at the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module.

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice way to override.